# Get row of inserted id in rails transaction with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
#which receives Group objects and saves them in a transaction

def saveGroup(group_buffer)
    self.transaction do
        output = group_buffer.each(&:save)
        if(!output)
            return false
            break
        elsif( #I want the inserted row id as they are inserted)
            #put inserted row id in array
        end
    end
    return #the_array
end
```

Is this possible? Basically, what I want is to **obtain the inserted row id in a transaction as the objects are saved and push it into an array**. What is the best way to do this? Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? if any instance will not save, the transaction will roll back, so you don't have to brake it manually.

```
def saveGroup(group_buffer)
    ids = []
    self.transaction do
        group_buffer.each do |i|
         i.save
         ids << i.id
        end
    end
 if ids.empty?
  false
 else
  ids
 end
end
```